# Relationship between Session and endpoints is OPC UA

Tags: opc-ua, opc

Given a UA Server with three endpoints, a Session has been created.

Is the session strictly tied to one endpoint?

If not, then does a session share all the endpoints User Token Policy? e.g. if a client sends a request with a Policy ID, should the server look for a match by iterating the Policy ID of all the endpoints?

Could you please link some points where this is discussed in the specifications or similar resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the session is created with one endpoint. After that it is activated with one of the user token policies of the endpoint.

Look for [CreateSession](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/docs/Part4/5.6.2/) and [ActivateSession](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/docs/Part4/5.6.3/) in the specifications.